# Import SQL Google Cloud SQL : HTTPError 403: Insufficient Permission

Tags: import, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I followed the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/import/sql) in the Google Cloud SQL SDK for importing data.

But when I change information using the command:

```
gcloud sql import sql test-instance-1 \
      gs://test-bucket/test-file.sql.gz --database=testdb
```

I receive the following error

```
(gcloud.sql.import.sql) HTTPError 403: Insufficient Permission
```

How can I rectify this fault?

Comment: are you sure you have write permission?

Comment: Where are you attempting to run the command from? From the Cloud Shell or from a GCE instance?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're getting the error by running the command from a GCE instance.

The issue is due to not having enabled access from the instance, to the necessary Cloud APIs.

To solve it, do the following:

1. Stop the GCE instance you want to connect from.
2. Select the instance, and then click on Edit.
3. Go all the way down where it says Access Scopes and click on it.
4. Select the 'Allow full access to all Cloud APIs' option and save the changes.
5. Start the GCE instance.